# Rest API call using Jquery Ajax with authentication token

Tags: ajax, rest, token

I want to consume REST api and for that I have only url and the authentication token. I am using Jquery Ajax call for this purpose. I am getting error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Below is my code sample

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://xxxx",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: { "api_token": "xxxx", "api_token_secret": "xxx" },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

this code is in jsfile and that js file I am included in index.html page. on document ready I am calling this function. 
If I didn't add the datatype : jsonp it is giving error of 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value

Can anyone please help me? What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
data: { "api_token": "xxxx", "api_token_secret": "xxx" },
```

should be this:

```
data: { api_token: "xxxx", api_token_secret: "xxx" },
```

You shouldn't quote the data keys.

Comment: Sorry that is not the case. By mistake in question I have added single quote. it is Actually have the same quotes both side

Comment: OK - I think I found the real issue

Comment: Sorry Again, still it is not working. I have change that too. but facing same issue.